# Blackberry project signing issue

Tags: blackberry, java-me

> Please contact the signer and register with the Signing Authority.

I see the above message, and also status `Not Registered` when I sign my application. I use the BrowserField in my project. When I exclude the code of BrowserField in my app, it doesn't show this message.

Comment: Did you install all three keys?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [BrowserField API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html), it does not need signing so, why does the device complain?

Comment: It might be something else. Possibly he has installed only one of the three keys, or maybe two, you catch my drift.